# Azure downtime events - historical list available?

Tags: hosting, azure

I am considering Azure for hosting and was curious if there is a list maintained of their downtime events... giving type of event, event time, outage type...  Basically - how often has  Azure hosted servers/storage/networks gone down?  A Google search is cluttered with individual events, but I'd like an overview of all major events.

Answer (score 3):

They have a status site where you can scroll through the days and it will list all events that happened for each service.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/